# Do Bangladeshi with a Portuguese D visa need a transit visa in Barcelona airport?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas, portugal

I am Bangladeshi, have Portuguese D visa(PhD purpose). Booked a ticket by Qatar Airways Dhaka to Lisbon.The travel itinary is Dhaka - Doha - Barcelona - Lisbon. But in Barcelona I have 6 hours layover and it is mentioned that Qatar airways operated by Vueling. Do I need a transit visa for Spain?

I have tried to contact as many places as possible but still get no response. If it is possible then response please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need transit visa if your D visa is in order. Both Spain and Portugal are in Schengen, so you will clear the immigration in Barcelona. Your Vueling flight from BCN to LIS would be "domestic" and you will not go through the passport control in LIS.